# Leave the type of a List in a class vague until populated

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

In a user-defined class, I'd like to leave the type of a List ambiguous so that I could have a list of strings or integers or tuples in separate instances of the class (that is to say, each list would be of only one type, but different instances of the class would different types). I currently have something like:

```
public Result
{
    private List<dynamic> _vaguelist;
    public List<dynamic> vaguelist {
        get
        {
            return _vaguelist;
        }
        set
        {
            _vaguelist = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I'm pretty sure I'm not using the dynamic type properly. I think I would need a constructor that creates a new List where T gets determined from the GetType() of the first value added to the Class. Or write the List to be designated a certain type when it is initialized.

In short, how can I define a list within a class such that the type of its values can either be inherent of whatever is added to the list or specified when the class is instantiated? (values within a single list will all be of ONE type).

Comment: It sounds like you need to go and [read about Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Comment: Why not make `Result` generic?

Comment: Do you want to fill the list with different types at the same time, ie with heterogeneous types?

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe that seems like it might be a very viable option.

Comment: @MethodMan could you maybe elaborate on what is unclear so that I can remedy the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two options, the first one beign the best approach, will only work if you know the list will be of a certain type.

```
public class Result<T>
{
    private List<T> _vaguelist = new List<T>();
    public List<T> vaguelist {
        get
        {
            return _vaguelist;
        }
        set
        {
            _vaguelist = value;
        }
    }
}

Result a = new Result<string>();
a.vaguelist.Add("1234");
Result b = new Result<int>();
a.vaguelist.Add(1234);
```

The second option will work if you wan't to add more than one type into the list o you won't know what you're putting into the list

```
public class Result
{
    private List<object> _vaguelist;
    public List<object> vaguelist {
        get
        {
            return _vaguelist;
        }
        set
        {
            _vaguelist = value;
        }
    }
}

Result a = new Result();
a.vaguelist.Add("1234");
a.vaguelist.Add(1234);
```

The problem with this approach is that you will have to cast every single item in the list in order to take advantage of the type the item is.

---

Making use of the first approach, you could implement it like this:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    private List<T> _vaguelist = new List<T>();
    public List<T> vaguelist {
        get
        {
            return _vaguelist;
        }
        set
        {
            _vaguelist = value;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Result
{
    public static Result<T> NewResultFromItem<T>(T item)
    {
        Result<T> result = new Result<T>();
        result.vaguelist.Add(item);

        return result;
    }
}

string item1 = "123";
string item2 = "234";
var result = Result.NewResultFromItem(item1);
result.vaguelist.Add(item2);
```

Comment: The lists will only ever contain one type so example "1" is well suited. But could you explain your implementation of example "1"? Does it just save the hassle of an explicit type casting in the instantiation?

Comment: @ncarmona That's right the abstract class with the `NewResultFromItem` method will let you create a new `Result<T>` class withouth having to worry to cast it explicitly. You can always use `new Result<T>` anyways, and it'll work.

Comment: I'm getting a NullReferenceException for "vaguelist" stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Going out on a limb here, but do I need to instantiate the List<T> the first time I add something to it? My thought is that since the compiler can't implicitly cast a type for the list maybe it needs to instantiated explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, we just had to init _vaguelist to an empty list, i've edited the code, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for both type safety and type agnosticism (I just made up that word), which you cannot have both at the same time. Suppose you would find a way to make the list flip to a type safe collection at runtime when the first item is added. Who or what would be able to use it as such if you cannot code against it? The compiler will not know what it is going to be at runtime so there is not much that can be done for type safety. At runtime you would still have to figure out what you are dealing with so from a coding perspective it would still be just a list of objects.